# How to reference System.Management.Automation in a .NET Framework 4.7.2?

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

I started a new .NET Framework 4.7.2 library project.  I need to automate PowerShell scripts, but the "framework" tab in Visual Studio's reference adding UI didn't list System.Management.Automation as an option.  So I added a reference to this Nuget package:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Management.Automation/7.0.0

Then with this code:

```
PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
ps.AddScript(@"C:\ps\function.ps1");
ps.AddArgument(1);
ps.AddArgument(2);
Collection<PSObject> results = ps.Invoke<PSObject>();
```

I get this error about versions of a DLL which I did not directly reference:

> Assembly 'System.Management.Automation' with identity 'System.Management.Automation, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' uses 'System.Linq.Expressions, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'System.Linq.Expressions' with identity 'System.Linq.Expressions, Version=4.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

I'm not sure how to resolve this, and I think maybe I approached adding my PowerShell automation library reference the wrong way.  What's the right way to do this currently?

Before you point me at an old answer, I found a similar question about this which points to a different Nuget package, now marked "deprecated" and doesn't look official anyway.  That makes me nervous.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Management.Automation.dll/

Comment: Add a reference to  another https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Expressions/ ?

Comment: Link to system management automation in the global assembly cache?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`System.Management.Automation v7.0.0` only works with .NET Core.  If your project requires .NET Framework, you must use `System.Management.Automation v5.1.x`.

Comment: Thanks - where would I get that version, then?  Doesn't seem to available from the same nuget collection linked above.

Comment: For 5.1, you should use https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.PowerShell.5.ReferenceAssemblies/

Comment: Tried to install the nuget package for version 5.1, but it wasn't compatible with my framework version 4.6, so I used the one @SteveLee suggested above.

Answer (score 5):

I use `System.Management.Automation.dll` in my `.net framework 4.7.2` app.
I just added it via the following reference:

```
C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Management.Automation\1.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Management.Automation.dll
```