# Cannot find reference for System.Management.Automation in Visual Studio (.Net Framework 4.6.2 )

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reference, system.management

So I have view this link: [How to reference System.Management.Automation in a .NET Framework 4.7.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61017117/how-to-reference-system-management-automation-in-a-net-framework-4-7-2)

"you must use System.Management.Automation v5.1.x." this could works for me

But I want to find out if I can use System.Management.Automation without install any reference using Nuget. (like from the native machine, add reference is fine.)

I try to find through assembly but nothing. I have verified that there exist `System.Management.Automation.dll` in all these three location:

```
C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Management.Automation\1.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35
C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\WindowsPowerShell\3.0
```

Also, since I can fine the dll file, so I followed this link (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/install-assembly-into-gac) to install an assembly into the global assembly cache. But still not work.

Only `System.Management` and `System.Management.Instrumentation` in (Assemblies) Add Reference table.

Please help,

Many thanks!

Comment: @ Avenger_Shadow. What method did you use to add Microsoft.PowerShell.5.ReferenceAssemblies? Did you use the command Install-Package Microsoft.PowerShell.5.ReferenceAssemblies -Version 1.1.0 here to download dependencies in visual studio? Could you try this download method (right click on the .Net Framework project and select Manage Nuget Packages...->Search and download Microsoft.Powershell.5.ReferenceAssemblies) to check if the problem can be solved?

Comment: Thanks for reply, Yes this can be resolved by download that. I'm using System.Management.Automation.

Comment: @ Avenger_Shadow. I have updated the comment to the answer. If it is solved your problem, you can click ‘✔’ to accept it as an answer. It is helpful for community members to solve the similar problems.

Answer (score 2):

For downloading **Microsoft.PowerShell.5.ReferenceAssemblies** in visual studio, you could try this download method (right click on the .Net Framework project and select Manage Nuget Packages...->Search and download Microsoft.Powershell.5.ReferenceAssemblies) to check if the problem can be solved.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, yes, I know how to download that using Nuget in Visual Studio, I'm trying to find a way NOT using that. The System.Management.Automation.dll is already there as I mentioned, I'm not too sure which package to include though.